# Javascript: how to fill part of the page with html frome some url and update it ragulary?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have simple html web page with one div with `id="toFill"` on it. Page has header script stule and body blocks. I have some file like markUpToAdd.html with for example html list (no header body etc - just `<ul> <li>` etc) jo my server will update file from time to time. I need using Javascript  to put contents of markUpToAdd into that div and update each 30 seconds. How to do such thing? Not using Jquery or any special libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're not using a library, you'll have to do it he long way...

```
function update(){
 var xmlhttp;
 try{
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch(e){
  var success = false;   
  var objects = ["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
  for(var i=0; i<objects.length && !success; i++){
   try{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(objects[i]);
    success = true;
   }catch(e){};
  }
  if(!success) throw new Error("AJAX is unavailabe");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
   document.getElementById('toFill').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  };
 }
 xmlhttp.open("get", "markUpToAdd.html", true);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
}
update();
setInterval(update, 30000);
```

untested.  could also be optimized (only need to determine the XHMLTTPRequest object once instead of during each tick).

Comment: yes, it should.  the browser will only matter insofar as the availability of the XMLHTTPRequest object and document.getElementById, so should be fine in IE5+, all versions of Chrome and Fx, safari, etc.  AFAIK iPhone uses a version of safari, so that should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery you can use the function jQuery.get() [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/]

$.get("markUpToAdd.html", function(data){
   $('#toFill').innerHtml = data;
 });